# Querying/searching a List in LINQ (under some circumstances)

Tags: c#, linq

How can I get the contents of every list entry to be tested against `textQuery.Text` and if it is a hit, to be written to the FOUR columns in a ListView named `listResx`?

```
List<TransResource> MasterList = new List<TransResource>();

foreach (TransResource x in resources.Values)
{
     MasterList.Add(x);
}
...
public class TransResource
{
    public string id {get; set;}
    public string en {get; set;}
    public string fr {get; set;}
    public string es {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I am confused as to what you are asking. Where is textQuery.Text? What query operator do you wish to use (e.g. what are we searching for, what defines a "hit")? Where is our source data?

Comment: Maybe this can help in the future: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var resultList = MasterList.Where(x => x.id == textQuery.Text || x.en == textQuery.Text || x.fr == textQuery.Text || x.es == textQuery.Text).ToList();
```

That should give you smaller resulting list of matches. Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

```
string keyword = textQuery.Text;

var hitsQuery = from i in MasterList
                where i.en == keyword ||
                      i.es == keyword ||
                      i.fr == keyword ||
                      i.id == keyword
                select i;

var hits = hitsQuery.ToList();
```

`hist` would be `List<TransResource>`. You can use it to populate your `ListView`, e.g. using `DataSource` property:

```
listResx.DataSource = hits;
listResx.DataBind();
```

Comment: Unfortunately WinForms' ListView has no DataSource and DataBind ala WebForms. Also, `MasterList` isn't the source of data, it's `resources.Values`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var matches = resources.Values.Where(x=>x.id==txtQuery.Text ||
                                        x.en==txtQuery.Text ||
                                        x.fr==txtQuery.Text ||
                                        x.es==txtQuery.Text);

foreach(var item in matches)
{   
   string displayItem = item.id + " " + item.en;
   listResx.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(displayItem));
}
```

Or go with fewer lines of code:

```
foreach(var item in resources.Values.Where(x=>x.id==txtQuery.Text ||
                                              x.en==txtQuery.Text ||
                                              x.fr==txtQuery.Text ||
                                              x.es==txtQuery.Text))
{   
   string displayItem = item.id + " " + item.en;
   listResx.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(displayItem));
}
```